# Is this Index checking logic ok?

Tags: sql-server, index-statistics

I am writing a script to quickly check the indexes in a given database. I think I have the script written ok but to remove duplicate rows I have done alot of `SUM` functions and I am unsure whether this is correct or not:

```
SELECT      OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id)                                                                                                                AS 'Table Name'
,           COALESCE(i.name, '')                                                                                                                    AS 'Index Name'
,           i.type_desc                                                                                                                             AS 'Index Type'
,           i.is_primary_key                                                                                                                        AS 'Primary Key'
,           i.is_disabled                                                                                                                           AS 'Index Disabled'
,           ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT,SUM(user_seeks)) / (CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(NULLIF(SUM(user_scans),0),1))),2)                                          AS 'Seeks Per Scan'
,           ROUND((CONVERT(FLOAT,SUM(user_seeks) +SUM(user_scans) + SUM(user_lookups))) / (CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(NULLIF(SUM(user_updates),0),1))),2) AS 'Reads Per Write'
,           (SUM(user_seeks) + SUM(user_scans) + SUM(user_lookups))                                                                                 AS 'Reads'
,           SUM(user_updates)                                                                                                                       AS 'Writes'
,           SUM(user_seeks)                                                                                                                         AS 'Seeks'
,           SUM(user_scans)                                                                                                                         AS 'Scan'
,           ROUND(AVG(ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent),2)                                                                                           AS 'Avg Fragmentation %'
,           NULLIF((SUM(leaf_insert_count) + SUM(leaf_update_count) + SUM(leaf_delete_count)),0) / NULLIF(SUM(leaf_allocation_count),0)             AS 'Leaf Page Splits Per Write'
,           NULLIF((SUM(nonleaf_insert_count) + SUM(nonleaf_update_count) + SUM(nonleaf_delete_count)),0) / NULLIF(SUM(nonleaf_allocation_count),0) AS 'Non-Leaf Page Splits Per Write'
,           CAST (100.0 * SUM(row_lock_wait_count) / (1 + SUM(row_lock_count)) AS NUMERIC(15,2))                                                    AS 'Block %'
,           SUM(row_lock_wait_in_ms)                                                                                                                AS 'Row Lock Wait (ms)'
,           CAST(1.0 * SUM(row_lock_wait_in_ms) / (1 + SUM(row_lock_wait_count)) AS NUMERIC(15,2))                                                  AS 'Average Row Lock Wait'
FROM sys.indexes i
LEFT JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = i.object_id 
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) s ON o.object_id = s.object_id AND i.index_id = s.index_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats u ON s.object_id = u.object_id AND u.index_id = s.index_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS ps ON u.index_id = ps.index_id AND u.object_id = ps.object_id
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(o.object_id,'IsUserTable') = 1 
AND NOT OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id) = 'sysdiagrams' -- exclude sysdiagrams
--AND i.is_primary_key = 0
GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id), COALESCE(i.name, ''),i.type_desc,i.is_primary_key,i.is_disabled
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id), COALESCE(i.name, '')
```

Is this ok? Or is `SUM`ing the rows bad?

Also, is there any information that you think would be helpful for finding indexes that aren't used/need re-indexing etc

Comment: I'd normally separate the queries out: one for fragmentation, one for missing, one for unused etc

Comment: @gbn, I can understand that. The aim of this was to see if I could get the best of all the scripts (except missing indexes) into 1 script/view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use one of the scripts which are out there and available for free.  The current reigning version of the one posted on [sqlfool.com](http://sqlfool.com).

Comment: because im trying to learn, i dont think anyone can learn by copy - paste - execute

Comment: No but you can learn by reading the code that has been written and figuring out how it works.  Code that hasn't been reviewed and understood shouldn't ever be put into production, no matter who wrote it.